# How can I query on MySQL data snapshot using Python?

Tags: python, mysql, database

I'd like to create a snapshot of a database periodically, and execute some queries on the snapshot data to generate data for next step. Finally I want to discard the snapshot.

I read and convert all data into memory data structure(python dict) from the database and execute queries(implemented by my own code) on data structure

The program have a bottleneck  on "execute query" step after data size increased

How can I query on data snapshot elegantly? Thanks much for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

you can get all tables from your database with

```
SHOW TABLES FROM <yourDBname>
```

after that you may create copies of the tables in a new DB via

```
CREATE TABLE copy.tableA AS SELECT * FROM <yourDBname>.tableA
```

afterwars you can query the copy-database instead of the real data. 
if you do queries on the tables, pls add indexes since they are not copied.